# C++ console app call C++/CLI static library

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I'm playing around with the idea of creating a C++/CLI static library which exposes a number of static functions for the managed EventLogger functionality. My current Solution exists out of a `/clr` compiled C++ project and a C++ console app.

Visual Studio tells me that the ConsoleApp needs to be compiled with the `/clr` parameter but that's something I don't want to do. Is there some way of achieving what I'm trying to do here?

```cpp
#### ConsoleApp.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "../ClrEtwLogger/ClrEtwLogger.h"

int main()
{
    clr_etw_logger::etw_logger::etw_log();
}
```

```cpp
#### ClrEtwLogger.h (/clr), static library

#pragma once

#using <system.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace Diagnostics;

namespace clr_etw_logger
{
    public ref class etw_logger
    {
    public:
        static void etw_log()
        {
            const auto source = gcnew String("dotNet ClrEtwLogger");
            const auto log = gcnew String("EtwLogger");
            const auto event = gcnew String("Sample Event 1");

            if (!EventLog::SourceExists(source))
            {
                EventLog::CreateEventSource(source, log);
            }

            EventLog::WriteEntry(source, event);
            EventLog::WriteEntry(source, event, EventLogEntryType::Warning, 234);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You cannot create a static C++/CLI library, it must be a DLL.  Calling managed code from native code (aka "reverse pinvoke") is quite risky, C++/CLI is optimized to do the opposite.  It isn't impossible (use __declspec(dllexport) on the functions), making it reliable is the bigger issue.  Managed code likes throwing exceptions and you'll have no idea whatsoever what went wrong in your native code when that happens.  If you write this library only to get the benefit of ETW logging then just make it native.

Comment: From what I've seen is that the native implementation of such a library would take a lot more effort than trying to do it through C++/CLI. After I posted this I realized that a static library doesn't make much sense here so I changed it to a dynamic library. I'll try to research the __declspec as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can wrap your managed code in an unmanaged function and call it from your managed project by following these steps,

**1>** Create an **empty project c++** project

**2>** Set Common Language Runtime Support to **Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)** in the **Configuration** -> **Advanced** page

**3>** In Configuration > C++ > Command Line, add this text to clear a linker error -> **/Zc:twoPhase-**

**4>** Set the .NET version to a version you have installed in the **Configuration** -> **Advanced** page in the .NET Framework Version field for example 4.8

**5>** Add References to the necessary Dlls

in my example, I had referenced the following assemblies

```
System
System.Data
System.Windows.Forms
System.Drawing
```

**6>** in the **Configuration** -> **General** page, change the **Configuration Type** to static library,

**7>** in the **Configuration** -> **Advanced** page, change the **Target File Extension** to **.lib**
In this example the code is compiled in main.cpp with no header files

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Windows;

namespace MyApp
{
    public ref class MyForm : public Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ProgressBar^ GetProgressBar() {
            return pgb;
        }

    protected:
        ~MyForm() {

        }

    private:
        ProgressBar^ pgb;

        void InitializeComponent() {
            pgb = gcnew ProgressBar();
            SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // progressBar
            // 
            pgb->Dock = DockStyle::Fill;
            pgb->Location = Drawing::Point(0, 0);
            pgb->Name = "pgb";
            pgb->Size = Drawing::Size(200, 20);
            pgb->TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            ClientSize = Drawing::Size(200, 20);
            Controls->Add(pgb);
            auto fs = Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedSingle;
            this->FormBorderStyle = fs;
            MaximizeBox = false;
            MinimizeBox = false;
            Name = "MyForm";
            auto sp = FormStartPosition::CenterScreen;
            StartPosition = sp;
            Text = "My Form";
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    };
}
    void ShowProgress() {
        auto f = gcnew MyApp::MyForm();
        f->TopMost = true;
        f->Show();
        f->GetProgressBar()->Visible = true;
        f->GetProgressBar()->Minimum = 1;
        f->GetProgressBar()->Maximum = 100;
        f->GetProgressBar()->Value = 90;
        f->GetProgressBar()->Step = 1;

        auto fv = f->GetProgressBar()->Value;
        while (fv < 10)
        {
            f->GetProgressBar()->Value += 1;
            Thread::Sleep(1);
            f->Update();
        }

        f->Close();
    }

    void RunProgress() {
        try {
            auto ts = gcnew ThreadStart(ShowProgress);
            auto t = gcnew Thread(ts);
            t->SetApartmentState(ApartmentState::STA);
            t->Start();
            t->Join();
        }
        catch (Exception^ e) {
            // TODO: Handle any exceptions
        }
    }

    void ShowProgressBar()
    {
        MyApp::MyForm^ form = nullptr;
        form = gcnew  MyApp::MyForm();
        form->TopMost = true;
        form->Show();
        form->GetProgressBar()->Visible = true;
        form->GetProgressBar()->Minimum = 1;
        form->GetProgressBar()->Maximum = 100;
        form->GetProgressBar()->Value = 1;
        form->GetProgressBar()->Step = 1;
        auto i = 0;

        if (form)
        {
            while (form->GetProgressBar()->Value < 100)
            {
                form->GetProgressBar()->Value += 1;
                form->Update();
                Thread::Sleep(1);
            }
            form->Close();
        }
    }
     //this is the function to be exported
    extern "C" void RunProgressBar()
    {
        try
        {

            Thread^ progressBarThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(ShowProgressBar));
            progressBarThread->SetApartmentState(ApartmentState::STA);
            progressBarThread->Start();
            progressBarThread->Join();

        }
        catch (System::Exception^ e)
        {

            // Your main application code here


        }
    }
```

Then you can call the code from your unmanaged project
by referencing the library and defining the imported function like so

```
#pragma comment(lib, "RunProgressBarLib.lib") 
// Creates a progress bar for 
//a short amount of time
extern "C" void RunProgressBar();
```

There are some limitations to what version of c++ you can use, c++17 may not be compatible with clr,

It is also critical to handle exception at the .NET level lest they cause a crash in the unmanaged code.